# content inset to move the table view when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

im stuck with a simple issue of moving my tableview when the keyboard shows.
i dont want to move the frame using animations, instead i want to use content inset to move the table view.

my notification is being called bt it doesnt move the tableview.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"%@",self.tableView1);

    NSValue *keyboardBoundsValue = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [keyboardBoundsValue getValue:&keyboardBounds];
    UIEdgeInsets e = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardBounds.size.height, 0);
NSLog(@"%d %d %d %d",self.tableView1.contentInset.bottom,self.tableView1.contentInset.top,self.tableView1.contentInset.left,self.tableView1.contentInset.right);    
    [self.tableView1 setContentInset:e];
    [self.tableView1 setScrollIndicatorInsets:e];
    NSLog(@"%d %d %d %d",self.tableView1.contentInset.bottom,self.tableView1.contentInset.top,self.tableView1.contentInset.left,self.tableView1.contentInset.right);

NSLog(@"%@",self.tableView1);
NSLog(@"keyboard notification");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe you try to do here is making the scroll area of the table smaller in order to not have the keyboard overlap the table. In that case, maybe you should put

```
UIEdgeInsets e = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardBounds.size.height, 0);
```

instead of `keyboardBounds.size.width`. If you want to "move" the table, then you can do that only by modifying its `frame.origin` or its `center`.

Comment: i had height.. i had written width to test something else, by mistake that was copied here.. im using height only, still its not working.

Comment: i'm not sure, does the nsvalue give you the correct height of the keyboard (it should be 216); if not you could try it like this NSNumber *keyboardHeight = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height];